# Inserting jquery next to eachother?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I need help, Im using JCapSlide and I want 4 tiles to go across my header however when I add them they just get inserted below eachother. What do I do to insert them next to one another.

Here is my code for one of them now how do I go about inserting another to the right of this

```
<div id="header_image_home">
        <div id="capslide_img_cont6" class="ic_container">
                <img src="images/example2.jpg" width="180" height="240" alt=""/>
                <div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div class="ic_caption">
                    <class="ic_category">Categor
                    <h3>Amazing Image Title</h3>
                    <class="ic_text">
                       Description Here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

The top row of the demo here http://tympanus.net/jCapSlide/ is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What is your css for the `ic_container` class? My first thought is that you just need to `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `float:left` CSS styling to the elements.

Comment: How would I go about moving the whole lot of them a little bit to the right now so theyre center

Comment: probably you will want to make a wrapper around all of them then add margin: 0 auto; or whatever to the wrapper

Comment: It is also polite to mark as answer if this solved the problem described.

Comment: better late than never

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `float: left;` in this case, and do not forget to put an `overflow: hidden;` on the containing div or a `clear: both;` on the following one.